# Can Bunjs be used as a backend server?

Tags: bun

Now we can start a react App with bun as a server

Can we use Bunjs as complete backend server?

For Example, Can bun run this code?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess Bun does not YET implement all node.js api's. I tried http and it seems currently missing. And as much I understand it currently has its own built-in HTTP server.

Check the "Getting started" section on -> https://bun.sh/

A sample server:

```js
    export default {
      port: 3000,
      fetch(request) {
        return new Response("Welcome to Bun!");
      },
    };
```

(This example reminds me of serverless functions.)
As this is the case, it seems you can not rely on Node.js http, or most probably any server framework like express.

At least for now, bun's roadmap (https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/159) shows a line, which I am not sure is talking about node's http server or sth. else about Bun's own server.

> Once complete, the next step is integration with the HTTP server and
> other Bun APIs

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can**, and you don't even need an dependencies (like Express). Your example can be written as simply as:

```js
Bun.serve({
  port: 3000,
  fetch() {
    return new Response('hello world');
  },
});

console.log(`Running on port: ${serve.port}`)
```

```bash
bun run index.js
```

Then open http://127.0.0.1:3000 in a browser.

See the [Bun HTTP Docs](https://bun.sh/docs/api/http) for more server options like out-of-the box TLS support and WebSockets. Considering the benchmarks of Bun it's very capable as a backend server. Also see [Elysia](https://elysiajs.com/) as a very complete Bun based backend framework that [on their homepage] claims to handle 17 x more request/second that Express.

Answer (score 2):

To start a high-performance HTTP server with a clean API in Bun, the recommended approach is [`Bun.serve`](https://bun.sh/docs/api/http#bun-serve).
Also, the Node.js `http` and `https` modules have been re-implemented to use Bun's fast internal HTTP infrastructure, thus these modules can be used directly in Bun without any third-party tools.

To run an HTTP server, use [`Bun.run`](https://bun.sh/docs/cli/run) cli command.

#### Following are some uses of Bun as a backend server:

**Start a simple HTTP Server (on default port `3000`):**

```js
Bun.serve({
  fetch(req) {
    return new Response("Hello World!");
  },
});
```

**Configure which port and hostname the server will listen to:**

```js
Bun.serve({
  port: 8080, 
  hostname: "mypublicdomain.com", 
  fetch(req) {
    return new Response("Hello World!");
  },
});
```

Also, the `fetch` handler handles incoming requests by receiving the [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) object and returning a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) or `Promise<Response>`:

```js
Bun.serve({
  fetch(req) {
    const url = new URL(req.url);
    if (url.pathname === "/") return new Response("Welcome to Home page!");
    if (url.pathname === "/about") return new Response("Welcome to about page!");
    return new Response("404 not found!");
  },
});
```

**Streaming files with HTTP Server:**

You can use the `BunFile` object as the body of `Response` object to stream a file.

```js
Bun.serve({
  fetch(req) {
    return new Response(Bun.file("./sample.wav"));
  },
});
```

**Handle Request based on HTTP methods:**

```js
Bun.serve({
  fetch(req) {
    if(req.method === "GET") {
      return new Response("Get Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "POST") {
      return new Response("Post Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "PUT") {
      return new Response("Put Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "DELETE") {
      return new Response("Delete Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "PATCH") {
      return new Response("Patch Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      return new Response("Options Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "HEAD") {
      return new Response("Head Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "TRACE") {
      return new Response("Trace Response!");
    }
    else if(req.method === "CONNECT") {
      return new Response("Connect Response!");
    }
    return new Error("Something went wrong!");
  },
});
```

**To stop a server, call the `.stop()` method:**

```js
const server = Bun.serve({
  fetch() {
    return new Response("New server started!");
  },
});

server.stop(); // stops the server
```

Comment: it seems there is no way to change response status nor to add headers, isn't it ?

Comment: yes, there is actually , it is a second argument to the response , `Response("whatever", {status: 404, headers: {a:"b"}})`

Answer (score 1):

Other way is using Hono: https://honojs.dev/

There is a working demo: https://github.com/cachac/bun-api

1. Import package and set new instance

```
import { Hono } from 'hono'
const app = new Hono()
```

2. Create routes:
   Instead of NodeJs res.send(), use c.json({})

```
app.get('/hello', c => c.json({ message: 'Hello World' }))
```

3. export and run api server:

```
export default {
  fetch: app.fetch,
  port: 3000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've tried this, bun can now run express servers, although bun.Serve is faster.
To do this, just write your node JS code and run it with the command : *bun run your_file_name* or just *bun your_file_name*.

Answer (score 0):

Bun api is really different from nodejs, I created a library called [bunrest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunrest), a express like api, so new user does not need to learn much about bun.

Here is how to use it

Install the package from npm

```js
npm i bunrest
```

To create a server

```js
const App = require('bunrest');
const server = new App.BunServer();
```

After that, you can call it like on express

```js
server.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'succeed' });
});

server.put('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'succeed' });
});

server.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'succeed' });
});
```

To start the server

```js
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, [bun.js](https://bunjs.run) is a JavaScript runtime that allows you to run JavaScript code in the backend. It provides a simple way to create an HTTP server with the `Bun.serve` function. In the code below, a server is created and set to listen on port 8080.

```js
const server = Bun.serve({
  port: 8080,
  fetch(req) {
    return new Response("Hello Bun!");
  },
});

console.log('HTTP server started.');
```

However, if you find the HTTP API provided by Bun.js too simple for your needs, you can use [hono](https://npm-compare.com/hono). Hono is a small, simple, and ultrafast web framework that works on Node.js and Bun.js. It provides features such as routers to make it easier to develop a app.